# Names of parameters in constructor of kotlin class are removed by proguard even with -keep

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I have a class with the following constructor:

```
class Configuration @JvmOverloads constructor(val applicationId: String, typesToAutomaticallyLoad: List<AutoLoadableType>,
                                                    val isTestMode: Boolean = false, var userId: String? = null,
                                                    private var videoNetworks: List<MDNetwork> = MDNetwork.values().toMutableList(),
                                                    private var networks: List<MDAdNetwork> = MDNetwork.values().toMutableList(),
                                                    var loadingTimeoutMs: Long = 20000)
```

my proguard file:

```
-keep class mypackage.** {
    <init>(...);
    *;
}
```

with minify disabled i get:

```
   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String applicationId, @NotNull List typesToAutomaticallyLoad, boolean isTestMode, @Nullable String userId, @NotNull List videoNetworks, @NotNull List networks) {
      this(applicationId, typesToAutomaticallyLoad, isTestMode, userId, videoNetworks, networks, 0L, 64, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String applicationId, @NotNull List typesToAutomaticallyLoad, boolean isTestMode, @Nullable String userId, @NotNull List videoNetworks) {
      this(applicationId, typesToAutomaticallyLoad, isTestMode, userId, videoNetworks, (List)null, 0L, 96, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String applicationId, @NotNull List typesToAutomaticallyLoad, boolean isTestMode, @Nullable String userId) {
      this(applicationId, typesToAutomaticallyLoad, isTestMode, userId, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 112, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String applicationId, @NotNull List typesToAutomaticallyLoad, boolean isTestMode) {
      this(applicationId, typesToAutomaticallyLoad, isTestMode, (String)null, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 120, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String applicationId, @NotNull List typesToAutomaticallyLoad) {
      this(applicationId, typesToAutomaticallyLoad, false, (String)null, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 124, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }
```

with minify enabled i get:

```
   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull List var2, boolean var3, @Nullable String var4, @NotNull List var5, @NotNull List var6) {
      this(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, 0L, 64, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull List var2, boolean var3, @Nullable String var4, @NotNull List var5) {
      this(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, (List)null, 0L, 96, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull List var2, boolean var3, @Nullable String var4) {
      this(var1, var2, var3, var4, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 112, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull List var2, boolean var3) {
      this(var1, var2, var3, (String)null, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 120, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }

   @JvmOverloads
   public Configuration(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull List var2) {
      this(var1, var2, false, (String)null, (List)null, (List)null, 0L, 124, (DefaultConstructorMarker)null);
   }
```

So this proguard configuration keeps the class name, constructor names, but not parameter names.

How do I make it keep the parameter names too?

Answer (score 0):

You must add @SerializedName("...") with all parameters,

data class SyncUser(
    @SerializedName("user")
    val user: User
)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about Kotlin Metadata. I'd suggest two things here:

- Add the rules for that metadata file for ProGuard/R8:

```
    -keep class kotlin.Metadata
    -keep,allowobfuscation class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

- Ensure you're keeping the compatibility between Kotlin version, AGP and D8/R8 versions. A major change in the D8/R8 would break the Metadata file making it non interpretable for Kotlin. Ref: https://developer.android.com/build/kotlin-support